# DOM Image creation object not inserted into canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas :

```
<canvas id="mandarin" width="235" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

And I want to insert an image into the canvas when the window loads, however this code doesn't render anything:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var context = document.getElementById("mandarin").getContext("2d");
    var ourImage = document.createElement("IMG");
    ourImage.src = "mandarin.jpg";
    ourImage.setAttribute("width", 235);
    ourImage.setAttribute("height", 300);
    context.drawImage(ourImage, 10, 10);
};
```

But when I include this line , irrelevant of the code above and outside the body it works.

```
<img id="mandarinImg" src="mandarin.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="250" height="350">
```

But the problem is I have the canvas and the image side by side. All I need to display is the canvas with the image inside.

How would I insert this DOM image into the canvas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the source of the image (`ourImage.src = "mandarin.jpg"`) it is not loaded yet. This means if you draw the image afterwards it will not do it. Because your image isnt loaded. You should wait for the image to load and then draw it:

```
ourImage.onload = function(){
  context.drawImage(ourImage, 10, 10);
}
ourImage.src = "mandarin.jpg"
```

---

(Note that it's important to hook the event **before** setting `src`. There may be only one main JavaScript UI thread, but the **browser** is not single-threaded. It's perfectly valid for the browser to respond to your setting `src` by immediately triggering a `load` event, seeing the element doesn't have any handlers for it, and therefore not queuing a callback. And at least one browser circa ~2008 did, if the image was in cache and usable.)

Comment: BTW, w3schools is a poor resource. Recommend [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage says, _“If the image isn't yet fully decoded, then nothing is drawn.”_ And that an image that isn’t even fully loaded yet is not going to be fully decoded either is kinda obvious, so I guess that should do as “specification” of this behavior, would you agree?

Comment: @CBroe: Absolutely. (I also verified it experimentally, but that's not the same thing.) I was looking through that spec when Zammy posted this answer, hadn't found that bit yet.

Comment: Zammy - You mistake my purpose in commenting. A good answer **cites its sources**. I'm encouraging you to do that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have mistaken you for the OP actuallly.  But lets get  the unnecessary comments out of the way then.

Comment: Already had done. :-) But don't forget to update the answer.